# javascript test if array object exists

Tags: javascript, json

I've tried everything I can think of to test if an object exists in this json array.

```
var estimatedGateDeparture = typeof data.flightStatuses[i].operationalTimes.estimatedGateDeparture.dateLocal;
```

I know that this array is empty.  my code just stops running when it encouters the above line.  I've tried to test if the key is "in" the object.  Still dies.  it seems to me that if I use "typeof", that that would be a REALLY safe way to see what's going on.  Still dies.

this still doesn't work.  It catches when nothing is there, but when something IS there, it doesn't "see" it.

```
    if (data.flightStatuses[i].operationalTimes.length > 0)
         {var estimatedGateDeparture = data.flightStatuses[i].operationalTimes.estimatedGateDeparture.dateLocal;
      } 
else 
      {alert ("no statuses");
      }
```

Subset of Data:   So, I'm trying to pull out .estimatedGateDeparture.dateLocal

{"flightId":321439750,"carrierFsCode":"WN","flightNumber":"963","departureAirportFsCode":"BWI","arrivalAirportFsCode":"CHS","departureDate":{"dateLocal":"2014-01-12T16:05:00.000","dateUtc":"2014-01-12T21:05:00.000Z"},"arrivalDate":{"dateLocal":"2014-01-12T17:40:00.000","dateUtc":"2014-01-12T22:40:00.000Z"},"status":"S","schedule":{"flightType":"J","serviceClasses":"RY","restrictions":"F","uplines":[{"fsCode":"MDW","flightId":321477764},{"fsCode":"CLE","flightId":321444143},{"fsCode":"BNA","flightId":321436891}]},"operationalTimes":{"publishedDeparture":{"dateLocal":"2014-01-12T16:05:00.000","dateUtc":"2014-01-12T21:05:00.000Z"},"publishedArrival":{"dateLocal":"2014-01-12T17:40:00.000","dateUtc":"2014-01-12T22:40:00.000Z"},"scheduledGateDeparture":{"dateLocal":"2014-01-12T16:05:00.000","dateUtc":"2014-01-12T21:05:00.000Z"},"estimatedGateDeparture":{"dateLocal":"2014-01-12T16:05:00.000","dateUtc":"2014-01-12T21:05:00.000Z"},"flightPlanPlannedDeparture":{"dateLocal":"2014-01-12T16:15:00.000","dateUtc":"2014-01-12T21:15:00.000Z"},"estimatedRunwayDeparture":{"dateLocal":"2014-01-12T16:15:00.000","dateUtc":"2014-01-12T21:15:00.000Z"},"scheduledGateArrival":{"dateLocal":"2014-01-12T17:40:00.000","dateUtc":"2014-01-12T22:40:00.000Z"},"estimatedGateArrival":{"dateLocal":"2014-01-12T17:40:00.000","dateUtc":"2014-01-12T22:40:00.000Z"},"flightPlanPlannedArrival":{"dateLocal":"2014-01-12T17:35:00.000","dateUtc":"2014-01-12T22:35:00.000Z"},"estimatedRunwayArrival":{"dateLocal":"2014-01-12T17:35:00.000","dateUtc":"2014-01-12T22:35:00.000Z"}},"codeshares":[{"fsCode":"FL","flightNumber":"2963","relationship":"L"}],"flightDurations":{"scheduledBlockMinutes":95,"scheduledAirMinutes":80,"scheduledTaxiOutMinutes":10,"scheduledTaxiInMinutes":5},"airportResources":{"departureGate":"A3","arrivalGate":"B5"},"flightEquipment":

Comment: Define `dies`? Any errors in the log?

Comment: Did you try `if (data.flightStatuses[i]) { }`?

Comment: Can you post more code, it's pretty difficult to tell what you're actually trying to do. typeof is a native javascript function for determining the type of a variable. If you want to check is an array is empty you can just check the length, like if (myArray.length === 0)

Comment: Andy...  data.flightstatuses[i] exists.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: hobberwickey....  tying that now.  sounds like better approach than mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think what you want to do is this

```
if (data.flightStatuses.length > i){
       var estimatedGateDeparture = data.flightStatuses[i].operationalTimes.estimatedGateDeparture.dateLocal;
}
```

Comment: OK.  Trying that now.

Comment: Awesome!   Works like a champ!  I been trying to get this to work for hours.  thank YOU!

Comment: Hobberwickey...  I posted the code I used above.  It catches it if nothing is there but it alerts "no statuses" when it shouldn't.

Comment: You should provide an example for `data` where it fails now.

Comment: You didn't post the entire thing. And please don't just post your entire block of data. Make a small sample that shows the problem and show us that one.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere on your path is `undefined`, i.e.

```
var x;
var y=0;

console.log(x.a); // error: cannot read property 'a' of undefined
console.log(y.a); // undefined, no error
console.log(z.a); // error: 'z' is not defined
```

Therefore, you should test all the object on the path

```
var x, estimatedGateDeparture=null;
if(
  (x=data) &&
  (x=x.flightStatuses) &&
  (x=x[i]) &&
  (x=x.operationalTimes) &&
  (x=x.estimatedGateDeparture)
) estimatedGateDeparture = x.dateLocal;
```

or, if the performance isn't an issue and if you are lazy, just use exceptions:

```
var estimatedGateDeparture;
try { estimatedGateDeparture = data.flightStatuses[i].operationalTimes.estimatedGateDeparture.dateLocal; }
catch(e) { estimatedGateDeparture = null; }
```

Comment: The horrible thing about using exceptions is that you can easily shadow other problems that may occur. I dislike the `x = ...` thing, too, for other reasons, but to each their own. The general idea to check the entire path is correct, though.

Comment: @IngoBürk I agree on the exceptions, I just wanted to add them as possible option here. I like the `x = ...` for readability, but if you have better idea how to easily check entire path, I'd love to learn.

Comment: My preferred way would just be writing out every check. It's a bit lengthy, but not any less readable. In addition it avoids the variable which is both unnecessary and gets reassigned to lots of different things which I consider code smell. The only advantage -- imho -- is fewer characters of code, but that is not something that matters in good code. Though I can see how people might like this pattern, hence "to each their own" (and my +1).

Comment: (Since JSON is so common I'd actually love to see something similar to Groovy in JS where you could do `x.?flightStatuses[i].?...` for automatic `null` checks -- it's too bad we don't have this)

Comment: @IngoBürk maybe `x` could be advocated as path iterator here. In C, string can be iterated as `for(char* p=s; *p!=0; ++p)`, which is basically reasignment, too. However, in JS object assignment also uses references, which in microinstructions do fast stack jumps. The overhead could grow rapidly if the copy would be by value and `.` operator doesn't copy anything, so it could be recommended for users not aware how their language works behind the scene, indeed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try checking value returned by your object's "constructor" field:

```
var x = new User();
typeof x ==> returns "object"
x.constructor ==> returns "User"
```

I know you have an array but you can also use this method instead of typeof operator.